# What song is this?

Tags: cipher, steganography, music

The other day, me and my pal Davin were watching this super popular movie and I loved one of the songs I heard in it, and I play piano so I begged him to send me the sheet music for it because I didn't know the name ...but when he sent it, it looks like the file got corrupted during transit and looks like this now:

[image]

I couldn't make anything of it, so I asked Davin and he told me its fine, I just need to look harder and I'll find the song name so I can google it myself. So what song is this?

## HINT:

1. > What's in a name?
2. > You'll need at least a basic image editing program.
3. > The notes on the sheet music are irrelevant.

Comment: How did you make enumerated spoilers?

Comment: Manually, I just typed '1.' then the spoiler tag, pressed enter then '2.' then the spoiler tag.

Comment: @humn I discovered that little trick entirely by accident a few weeks ago. It only works for numbers, and only for a single line of spoilered text per number.

Comment: @humn you can always click the edit button of question to see how a question is formated

Comment: Based on nothing more than the songwriter, I'm going to guess Titanic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top of the image barely shows "Lyric by Will Jenning" -
Will Jennings wrote lyrics for some songs that have appeared in popular movies, including

> "My Heart Will Go On", which is in *Titanic* (Celine Dion)
>  "One Day I'll Fly Away", which is in *Moulin Rouge* (Nicole Kidman)
>  "Up Where We Belong", which is in *An Officer and a Gentleman* (Joe Cocker, Jennifer Warnes)

among others.  Having said that, here's the gist of the puzzle.

> Hint 2 tells us: **You'll need at least a basic image editing program.**
>  Hint 3 goes on to say: **The notes on the sheet music are irrelevant.**
>  Both of these point us to look at the image not for its content but for what it might be concealing.  And sure enough, there is text hidden in the image; replacing the white background with red, you see this:
>  [image]
>  which appears to read
>  **PYCMNUT**
>  **RQYOGJWA**

This is interesting, and points us the rest of the way.

> Thanks to a friendly reminder from **[@kayzeroshort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49912/what-song-is-this/49919?noredirect=1#comment152817_49919)** who points out we're given the friend's name, I take another look at Hint 1: **What's in a name?**
>
>  What, indeed.  What's in his pal Davin's name is, in fact, the key to the puzzle...
>  Using **DAVIN** as Vigenére key to the text we found, gives:
>  **MYHEART WILLGOON**
>
>  Making the name of the song entirely clear, and confirms that one of the songs I found from the lyricist's name is in fact the correct one.

So the song is

> **"My Heart Will Go On"**, and you were watching *Titanic*.

Comment: I wonder why he felt the need to include his friend's name in the story... ;)

Comment: @kayzeroshort Huh. Well spotted.